# error list indices must be integers, not list. Take values of one array use them as indexes to delete values from another array

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
seen = []
dups = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i, item in enumerate(prules)
    for j, orig in enumerate(seen):
        if item == orig:
            dups[j].append(i)
            break
    else:
        seen.append(item)
deleteindex = [val for key,val in dups.iteritems() if seen[key] == '159']
for i in range(o,len(deleteindex)):
    n = deleteindex[i]
    del rulelines[n]
```

The above is my code.

What I want to do is to create an array `deleteindex` which takes in the indice of any item with `159` in.

It does get all the values I want i.e all the indices with the value `159` but when I try to delete the values from a different array with the indices, it returns the error

> list indices must be integers, not list.

`prules` is the array I want to get the index values contains strings of numbers
`rulelines` contains is a list of strings which I want to use the values taken from `prules` and use the values as indexes to delete those values in `rulelines`

Where have I gone wrong?
I'm guessing its something at

```
deleteindex = [val for key,val in dups.iteritems() if seen[key] == '159']
```

Comment: Your whole code is not visible here, what is `prules`, and what is `rulelines` ?

Comment: I'm having a pretty tough time understanding what you're actually doing -- as evidenced by my now deleted answer that the community didn't agree with :-P ... Could you provide a minimal working example that demonstrates the problem (as well as an explanation of what you want) so we could play with it?  That would probably go a long way toward getting your solution.

Comment: If I wanted to count the number of occurrences of a value in a list, I'd use the `Collections.Counter` built-in data structure:

    from collections import Counter
    has_dups = set(item for item, count in Counter(prules).items() if count > 1)
    

and then proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.
The error is because, in

```
deleteindex = [val for key,val in dups.iteritems() if seen[key] == '159']
```

`key` is a `list`. As `dups` is `defaultdict(list)`, the value will always be a `list`.
This can be verified by:

```
...
print dict(dups.iteritems())  # adding this
deleteindex = [val for key,val in dups.iteritems() if seen[key] == '159']
...
```

As for your algorithm, try this, an easier to understand version.

```
import random

prules = [random.randint(150,156) for i in range(30)]

def get_indexes(li):
    retval = {}
    for i, x in enumerate(li):
        if x not in retval:
            retval[x] = []
        retval[x].append(i)
    return retval               

dups = get_indexes(prules)
indexes = dups.get('156',[])
rulelines = [rulelines[i] for i in range(len(rulelines[:])) if i not in indexes]
```

To get the indexes, just do:

```
dups.get('156',[])
```

Which will return a list of indexes if `dups['156']` exists, else it returns an empty list.

Comment: I still get an list assignment index out of range. I've printed n and i out and it does look like n is the values I want

Comment: Yes sorry `n` is what you want, but what is the length of `rulelines`? Is it equal to that of `prules`?? Also, we don't need the `enumerate`.

Comment: they are both the same length yeah

Comment: the size of `rulelines` decreases everytime `del rulelines[n]` is called, meaning the indexes at the end are no longer valid

Comment: they are too big as indexes, but at the start they would have been ok

Comment: @JohnSmith Solved now.. Updated [both](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15816817/1931274) the [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15813458/1931274)

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is right.

```
deleteindex = [val for key,val in dups.iteritems() if seen[key] == '159']
```

Here each `val` is one of the values in the `dups` dictionary you've been populating in the above loop. But what are these values? Well, `dups = collections.defaultdict(list)` would indicate that each one of these values is a `list`.

Therefore this code breaks due to your not keeping track of your types:

```
n = deleteindex[i]  # n is a list
del rulelines[n]    # you can't index a list with a list
```

Answer (score -1):

From what I can tell, `prules` is a list, or a collection at least that can be enumerated, in which case, you can possibly convert it to a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) which is all you need to do to remove duplicates.

---

However, if this is not the case (I can not tell since you have not provided that segment of code) then you could go about the whole thing in a better way:

```
seen = []
duplicate_indexes = []
for index, item in enumerate(prules):
    if item in seen:
        del rulelines[index]
    else:
        seen.append(item)
```

---

From your updated Question, I think that you are trying to do something else than what it seems your question is about. I think you are trying to delete every index in `rulelines` where the corresponding index in `prules` has a value of `'159'` if this is the case:

```
for ix, pr in enumerate(prules):
    if pr == '159':
        del rulelines[ix]
```