# stop list updating when using del python

Tags: python, list

I have a list where i want to delete certain elements from
I have created a for loop and in this for loop have put del my list[i]

`prule` is a list of strings containing things like numbers as strings from `0` to `159` its size `11154`

```
def getind(li)
    ret = {}
    for i, x in enumerate(li):
        if x not in ret:
            ret[x] = []
        ret[x].append(i)
    return ret
dups = getind(prule)
for n in dups.get('159',[]):
    del rulelines[n]
```

After a while of doing this `list assignment index out of range` which I am guessing is because the list gets updated. Is there anything I can use so it doesn't get updated until the for loop is finished

Comment: Are `prule` and `rulelines` supposed to be the same list?

Comment: @Schoolboy: I'm OK with closing as duplicate since the whole thing would have been better suited as a comment on the original answer before it was accepted. "Too localized" works too. *shrug*

Comment: Why do you need to delete the elements of the list while iterating over it?  If you want a list with only certain elements removed, you could create a new list and append elements to it for this purpose (and then rebind it to its original name, if desired), which is more pythonic if your inclusion condition is simple.  If you want to delete elements because memory is an issue, you could use a generator instead.

Comment: I agree, I flagged it too.. :). Why have the *shrug*??

Comment: @aestrivex There are 2 separate lists... See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15812181/1931274) question for the background

Answer (score 0):

You should browse your list backwards:

```
for x in range(subjectlength - 1, -1, -1):
    del my_list[x]
```

Comment: You really shouldn't copy and paste from other answers without attribution (original from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2057471/110707). This also won't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As I have corrected in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15813458/1931274)

```
dups = getind(prules)
indexes = dups.get('156',[])
rulelines = [rulelines[i] for i in range(len(rulelines[:])) if i not in indexes]
```

Should be what solves your problem.